# How can I show my backend api errors via the UI with axios React?

Tags: reactjs, validation, error-handling, axios, react-hooks

I have form validation set up on the backend.  I want to display this validation to the user on the front end.  I have a component that contains a popup modal.  Inside that component, I am trying to catch errors inside my useEffect and my onSubmit function.  And am trying to display those errors on the modal when the user tries to submit an incorrect value, for instance the user enters a password that isn't long enough.
What I am doing now, is not even catching the errors nor displaying them.  If I leave an input blank it should show that error message.  I am currently displaying errors via the UI from the UpdateValidation().  That will be removed once I am able to display the errors via the backend.

```
function EditModal({ close, companyId, employeeId }) {
    const { formValidation, formData, setFormData, firstNameError, lastNameError, emailError } = UpdateValidation();
    const isVisible = !!userId;
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
        });
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (employeeId !== null) {
                axios.get(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees/${employeeId}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        setFormData(res.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.response) {
                            setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                        }
                    })
            }
        }, [employeeId, setFormData, companyId])

    const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);
        const isValid = formValidation();
        if (isValid) {
            await axios.put(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees/${employeesId}`, formData)
                .then((res) => {
                    setFormData(res.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    debugger;
                    if (error.response) {
                        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                    }
                });
  
            close();
        }

    };
```

Removing some of this for context, this is part of my modal

```
return (
        <SprkModal
            title="Update user:"
            isVisible={isVisible}
            confirmText="Submit"
            cancelText="Cancel"
            cancelClick={() => {
                close();
            }}
            confirmClick={onSubmit}
        >
            <div className="modal">
                {errors.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="errors">
                        <p>{errors}</p>
                    </div>
                )}
                <label>First Name: </label>
```

I am a new developer so any help will greatly be appreciated.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I know the backend is set up correctly as I tested it with postman.
**EDIT**One reason this wasn't working was because of my if(isValid).  Since my catch was within that block it wasn't getting hit because it wasn't valid so it would never hit the catch.  I have since removed the isValid and am using a try catch.

```
try {

                await axios.put(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees`, formData)
                    .then((res) => {
                        setFormData(res.data);
                        close();
                    })
               
        }
        catch (error) {
            debugger;
            if (error.response) {
                setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                console.log(error.response.status);
            }

        }
```

I can now see the errors in the console.  But I am still not showing the errors on the UI.  I thought that this setErrors(error.response.data.errors); would set the errors and I could retrieve them in the UI by doing this

```
<div className="modal">
                {
                    errors.length > 0 && (
                        <div className="errors">
                            <p>{errors}</p>
                        </div>
                    )}
                <label>First Name: </label>
```

But it doesn't hit the errors.length....I tried to console.log(errors) and got an empty array.  When I check the react components I do see that the state is being set.  I'm not sure how to display it on the UI. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change this

```
   {
      errors.length > 0 && (
      <div className="errors">
         <p>{errors}</p>
      </div>
      )}
```

To this:

```
{Object.entries(errors).length > 0 &&
    Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => {
       return <div key={value[0]}>{value[0]}</div>;
  })}
```

And now it is working!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging response.status in the console?

example:

```
if(response) {
    console.log(response.status)
}
```

Comment: Just did.  I get a 200.

Comment: Well at least we know your request isn’t the issue. 
I’m not sure if you’re using context to hold you state and/or functions; but I recently had a project where I was storing all my state in context and using a custom hook to import my state through out my app. It was causing similar issues for me when dealing with forms. 
I moved my fetch requests into my component that was using it and my issues resolved.

Comment: Thank you Stephanie.  No I am not using context.

Comment: Maybe you could try wrapping the contents of your handleSubmit function in some conditional statements. Like; if(password.length <= 6){alert the user with your validation functionality}

Comment: I think I know what the issue is but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I removed my if(isValid) because if it was not valid it was just exiting out of that and not catching the error. because the catch was with in the isValid.  It is now catching the errors and I can console.log(error.response.status);  I am not sure how to set the errors so I can use them in the return to display on the ui.

Comment: You can say if response.status === 200 or whatever code you want and then have functionality based on each code. Or you can do it like this; if(response.status >= 400){this is bad mkay}

Comment: I don't understand how doing that will show the errors on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your technical problem but might solve the actual problem which amounts to "how can i give feedback to my users". Are you using any view libraries?

Most libraries have components or functions that will do that for you.

In Ant Design they call it a 'message' -> https://ant.design/components/message/
In Material Ui they call it a 'snackbar' -> https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/

Comment: No I am not using a view library